# Spring boot API not returning the updated data from the table

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

So what's happening is, my service is running fine. Fetching data. But the problem is when the table is updated in the database by some other client, the table gets updated but my service is returning the older snapshot of the table, not the updated one.
But on restarting the service, it does.

I am literally very new to Spring boot, tried a lot but no success.

Here's the relevant portion of code.

*SomeApi.java*

```
    @Autowired
    private FRPEntityManager frpEntityManager;

    @Autowired
    private DBI sqlDBI;
    
    public List<Workflow> getFRPStatusFromDB() throws Exception {
        Handle h = null;
        List<Workflow> workflowList;
        try {
            h = this.sqlDBI.open();
            h.begin();
            workflowList = this.frpEntityManager.getWfResponseFromDB(h);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            if (h != null) {
                h.rollback();
            }
            throw e;
        }
        finally {
            if (h != null) {
                h.close();
            }
        }

        return workflowList;
    }
```

*SqlDB.java*

```
@Configuration
@Component
public class SqlDB {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SqlDB.class);
    @Bean(name = "sqlDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.mysql.datasource")
    public DataSource sqlDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "sqlDBI")
    public DBI sqlDBI(@Qualifier("sqlDataSource") DataSource sqlDataSource) {
        LOG.info("SQL DBI initialized");
        synchronized (DBI.class) {
            DBI dbi = new DBI(sqlDataSource);
            LOG.info("This is SQL DBI");
            LOG.info(dbi);
            dbi.registerArgumentFactory(new DateTimeAF());
            return dbi;
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "sqlDbiFactory")
    public DBIFactoryBean sqlDbiFactory(@Qualifier("sqlDataSource") DataSource sqlDataSource) {
        final DBIFactoryBean dbiFactoryBean = new DBIFactoryBean();
        LOG.info("This is SQL Datasource");
        LOG.info(sqlDataSource);
        dbiFactoryBean.setDataSource(sqlDataSource);
        return dbiFactoryBean;
    }

    /**
     * @return the objectMapper
     */
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        return objectMapper;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean
    public MonitoringDAO sqlMonitoringDAO(@Qualifier("sqlDBI") DBI sqlDBI) {
        LOG.info("SQL MonitoringDAO initialized");
        return sqlDBI.onDemand(MonitoringDAO.class);
    }
}
```

*FRPEntityManager.java*

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class FRPEntityManager {

    // reading config from application.properties
    @Value("${env.value}")
    private String env;

    /**
     *
     * @param h
     * @return
     */
    public List<Workflow> getWfResponseFromDB(Handle h) {
        MonitoringDAO dao = null;
        dao = h.attach(MonitoringDAO.class);
        List<Workflow> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Map<String,String>> resultSet;
        resultSet = dao.getFRPWorkflowList();
        for(Map<String,String> r : resultSet) {

            Workflow result = new Workflow();
            result.setWorkflowID(r.get("id"));
            result.setStatus(r.get("status"));
            resultList.add(result);
        }
        return resultList;
    }
}
```

*MonitoringDAO.java*

```
@SqlQuery({{{some query}}})
    @Mapper(ResponseMapper.class)
    List<Map<String, String>> getFRPWorkflowList();
```

application.properties

```
spring.mysql.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.mysql.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=3
spring.mysql.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=2
spring.mysql.datasource.tomcat.max-active=20
spring.mysql.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=3
spring.mysql.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=10000
spring.mysql.datasource.tomcat.test-while-idle=true
spring.mysql.datasource.tomcat.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.mysql.datasource.tomcat.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=30000
spring.mysql.datasource.tomcat.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=30000
```